# How I set the space between a fbox and the paragraphs above and below the fbox?

Tags: floats

In my case, I do not use any command about it. So the text is very close with the box and it is not good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}


\begin{document}

P_above
\fbox{
 a=b
}
P_below
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the above and below "paragraphs" math expressions or text?  And are the above and below material really multi-line entities (paragraphs), or single-line entities?

Comment: `\[\boxed{a=b}\]` is probably what you want.

Comment: And is the `\fbox` centered like a separate equation, or left-justified?  And if centered, is it numbered like an equation?

Comment: I would recommend egreg's solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context is not clear to me, thus there might be better solutions.

The following example defines `\vsepfbox` that adds additional vertical space around the `\fbox` with size `\fboxsep`. `\sepfbox` puts the space all around the `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand*{\sepfbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\fbox{#1}}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \fbox{\unhbox0}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\vsepfbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\fbox{#1}}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
    \mbox{\kern-\fboxsep\fbox{\unhbox0}\kern-\fboxsep}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \qquad $P_\text{above}$\\
  $P_\text{left}$\fbox{$a=b$}$P_\text{right}$\\
  \null\qquad $P^\text{below}$

  \noindent
  \qquad $P_\text{above}$\\
  $P_\text{left}$\vsepfbox{$a=b$}$P_\text{right}$\\
  \null\qquad $P^\text{below}$

  \noindent
  \qquad $P_\text{above}$\\
  $P_\text{left}$\sepfbox{$a=b$}$P_\text{right}$\\
  \null\qquad $P^\text{below}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: why the `\null`?

Comment: @A.Ellett: At the begin of a line TeX removes white space like `\qquad`. `\null` is an empty box that prevents this.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the spacing using `\vsepfbox` ? How?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Probably yes. By adapting the macros to your need. Maybe, you make a new question, where you can describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options, but it's unclear what you really want.

If the boxed material is a math formula that should be centered, with `amsmath` you have `\boxed`. If the material is textual and you want it flush with the left margin, just place it inside a `flushleft` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\[
\boxed{a=b}
\]
\lipsum[3]
\begin{flushleft}
\fbox{some words}
\end{flushleft}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :)

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}

  $P_\text{above}$
  \fbox{
   a=b
  }
  $P_\text{below}$
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the OP wants _vertical_ space, i.e. the box in an own line ;-) btw. one should prefer using `$P_\text{below}$` to get the right font and spacing in the subscript text (needs `amsmath.sty`).

Comment: @subhamsoni: I agree with Tobi, that the OP probably meant vertical space above and below the boxed content, 'P_above' etc. are just place holders for paragraphs above etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have another answer based on the suggestions given. I think, this is the requirement.

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\quad $a=b$\quad}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]